# NSPredicate crash with path which contains square brackets

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate

I have to search paths which contains square brackets in it from core data.
But when I trying to create search query like below, xcode crashes.

`path == /my/local/[path]`

I've tried to escape square brackets, from one brackets to 16 brackets, but nothing works.

That path is from another application, so It couldn't be changed.
what should I have to do?
Thank you for your help in advance!

EDIT:
My code for making `NSPredicate` is like this.
`NSPredicate *preTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localFilePath == /[test]/"];`

UPDATE:
I found something weird.
`NSPredicate *testPre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localFilePath == %@", uploadFile.remotePath];`
`NSPredicate *what = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localFilePath == /"];`
Where uploadFile.remotePath equals @"/".
First one is ok, but second one crashes!

I think it seems to be related with my issue. Any ideas?
Thanks for allow your times on my issue! :)

Comment: add your code snippet for searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to match `[` and `]` you can use `matches` operator, which uses [regular expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp). Example:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"[apple]", @"[boy]", @"[dog]", @"cat"];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self matches %@", @"\\[dog\\]"];
NSLog(@"%@", [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred]);
```

---

About your update: `predicateWithFormat` is not like `stringWithFormat`, as it does some additional jobs that help to construct the predicate. For instance

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"localFilePath == %@", @"/"]
```

is equivalent to

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"localFilePath == \"/\""]
```

You can see that the quotation marks are added automatically. Also `predicateWithFormat` accepts some special substitutions like `%K` (for dynamic properties).

Apple provides a nice [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Predicates.pdf) about using predicates you may want to check out.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was late to try other ways to do this. I think there's no way to do this for another way. Thanks so much!